# Is there a coin time lock ability in Monero like the one in Bitcoin?

Tags: transaction-unlock-time

Is there a way to lock my Monero coins for X amount of time into the future? Like how bitcoin has a time lock feature on coins? I want to be able to just put some away and not ever use it until X amount of blocks.

Comment: Kind of duplicate of this one ^ no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *monero-wallet-cli* you can use the `locked_transfer` command to send money to yourself and lock it for a number of blocks.